# awk-sed joining of 3 tables with one nearly identical column... surely easier than python

Tags: join, awk, sed, tabular

I have a rather monolithic database I am re-building at the moment, and I want to join 3 tables with semi-matching content, I have several sets of these but they all come in groups of three.  Here is the situation:

--note all tables are in ascii format, space deliminated ---

T1_01= Table 1 =

```
1 + 'stuff1' + additional content 1  (where additional content only sometimes available)

2  ""

3  ""

....400
```

T1_02= Table 2 =

```
1 + "different stuff" + additional content 2

2 ""

3 ""

... 400
```

T1_03 = Table 3 =

```
5 cols yet other stuff + 001 + additional content 3

5 cols yet other stuff + 003    ""

5 cols yet other stuff + 007    ""

...

5 cols yet other stuff + 399   some rows are skipped, varies which ones

5 cols yet other stuff + 400
```

what I want, for each 'group' I have 3 tables, since these are grouped in a handy fashion, ie T1_01, T1_02, T1_03 would be table 1,2,3 for group 1, and again for T2_01,T2_02,T2_03.  I need to do this about 60 times in total and the table output I am hoping for is:

T1_0123=

```
1 + 'stuff1' + additional content 1 1 + "different stuff" + additional content 2 5 cols yet other stuff + 001 + additional content 3
2 + 'stuff1' + additional content 1 2 + "different stuff" + additional content 2 "something to fill in the empty spaces, like a set of -99.9 values"
3 + 'stuff1' + additional content 1 3 + "different stuff" + additional content 2 5 cols yet other stuff + 003 + additional content 3
...
400 ""
```

now I did an initial run and

`join -1 1 -2 1 T1_01 T1_02 > T1_012` works great, but only does the first two
and

`join -1 1 -2 6 T1_01 T1_03` ... does not work since 001 is not 1

and I was hoping to run all 3 tables in a go then do something like 
`sed something awk $(cat list_of_T01) $(cat list_of_T02) $(cat list_of_T03)` to run as a batch job.  I have been learning python so this may be possible there as well, but I surely AWK is easier?  Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Sometimes explaining a problem to a stranger prompts an answer from the questioner. I hope this is the case for you. Otherwise show examples of the real tables and desired result, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
join -1 1 -2 6 <(sed 's/^[0-9] /00&/;s/^[0-9][0-9] /0&/;' T1_01) T1_03
```

or this one if your delimiter isn't space:

```
join -1 1 -2 6 <(sed 's/^[0-9][^0-9]/00&/;s/^[0-9][0-9][^0-9]/0&/;' T1_01) T1_03
```

Comment: I think the delimiter is a tab, but I believe that it looks like a space for these purposes.  That said, I can't get a match using the above, I am 'matching' 1,2,3,...10,11,12,...399,400 with 001,002,003,...010,011,012,...399,400 in the corresponding file.  I 'think' that above it just adds zeroes??  Additionally I can only match 2/3 files in the way you suggest.  What I think I need is something where '00?' is replaced by '?' and '0??' is replaced by '??'.  Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: @user1594443 it is better to add zero before your nums, cause in both files without zeros it is the first column and you shouldn't care that it may affect other content. However in case you're gonna change the fifth column, regex become pretty complicated to avoid the possibility of changing some other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the help rush, I get it now. Additionally @potong, I thought that the actual giant tables might confuse the issue, but in here are the tops of the files. My T1_01 is:                                                                1 _P10644 0.816 123.04 2450.3 74.2 15.34 -1.553 -4.135  ,,         2 Parked ,,                                                         3 _P10569 0.791 146.30 2650.7 75.3 15.50 -1.478 -3.41  ,,

Comment: likewise T1_02 is:                                                    1 F1_P10644 P 1 4.89977691 -0.5104696 15.3 ,, 2 Parked N 2 4.88965087 -0.4904939 0.0 ,, 3 F1_P10569 P 3 4.89642427 -0.5099916 15.5 ,,

Comment: and T1_03 (which is causing most but not all of the problems): F1_P10644 4.899776910023531 -0.510469633262908 15.34 100606F1red 001 122.47 2.94 115.17 ,, F1_P10569 4.896424277974554 -0.509991655454702 15.50 100606F1red 003 145.55 2.72 138.25 ,, F1_P10769 4.906435995618358 -0.511246644149622 16.42 100606F1red 004 116.28 12.87 108.98 ,, where I have put in a ,, to indicate the new line to make this readable.